# How to remove focus from MyGUI Widget?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a MyGUI::ButtonPtr and on click of this widget I am showing a QWidget. By default focus is on QWdiget but it seems that MyGUI widget also has focus which is creating few issues for me.

```
myButton = widPtr.at(0)->findWidget("settings")->castType<MyGUI::Button>();
myButton->eventMouseButtonClick += MyGUI::newDelegate(this, settingsClicked);
addToolTip(myButton, "Tooltip text");


void addToolTip(MyGUI::Widget *widget, QString toolTipLabel)
{
    widget->eventToolTip += MyGUI::newDelegate(this, notifyTooltipEvent);
    widget->setNeedToolTip(true);
    widget->setUserString("tooltip", toolTipLabel.toStdString());
}
```

This tooltip should only be displayed on mouseover but it is visible also when button is clicked and QWidget is open which is incorrect. Reason for this seems to me that MyGUI button still has focus due to which tooltip is being displayed. I wish to remove this focus from MyGUI button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
MyGUI::InputManager::getInstancePtr()->injectMouseRelease(0, 0, MyGUI::MouseButton::Button0);
```